# Derivative of summations

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I am using sympy from time to time, but am not very good at it. At the moment I am stuck with defining a list of indexed variables, i.e. n1 to nmax and performing a summation on it. Then I want to be able to take the derivative:

So far I tried the following:

```
numSpecies = 10
n = IndexedBase('n')
i = symbols("i",cls=Idx)
nges = summation(n[i],[i,1,numSpecies])
```

However, if i try to take the derivative with respect to one variable, this fails:

```
diff(nges,n[5])
```

I also tried to avoid working with [`IndexedBase`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/indexed.html).

```
numSpecies = 10
n = symbols('n0:%d'%numSpecies)
k = symbols('k',integer=True)
ntot = summation(n[k],[k,0,numSpecies])
```

However, here already the summation fails because mixing python tuples and the sympy summation.

How I can perform indexedbase derivatives or some kind of workaround?

Comment: Thanks to Bill Bell and Stelios for the answers to my specific problem. I made my example as simple as possible, therefore it might seem real trivial. In the long run I need to define summations of more complicated equations. My problem is in the area of chemical engineering. Often you encounter equations where you have a sum of some kind of property weighted with  the respected mole fraction of a chemical species. Often it is necessary to calculate the derivative of said function with respect to the change of a specific species.

Comment: @Johannes You are welcome! I believe you should  now be able to handle more complicated problems like weighted sums. If you are still having problems, do not hesitate to post another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With SymPy's development version, your example works.

To install SymPy's development version, just pull it down with `git`:

```
git clone git://github.com/sympy/sympy.git
cd sympy
```

Then run python from that path or set the `PYTHONPATH` to include that directory before Python's default installation.

Your example on the development version:

```
In [3]: numSpecies = 10

In [4]: n = IndexedBase('n')

In [5]: i = symbols("i",cls=Idx)

In [6]: nges = summation(n[i],[i,1,numSpecies])

In [7]: nges
Out[7]: n[10] + n[1] + n[2] + n[3] + n[4] + n[5] + n[6] + n[7] + n[8] + n[9]

In [8]: diff(nges,n[5])
Out[8]: 1
```

You could also use the contracted form of summation:

```
In [9]: nges_uneval = Sum(n[i], [i,1,numSpecies])

In [10]: nges_uneval
Out[10]: 
  10      
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   n[i]
  ╱       
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 1     

In [11]: diff(nges_uneval, n[5])
Out[11]: 
  10      
 ___      
 ╲        
  ╲   δ   
  ╱    5,i
 ╱        
 ‾‾‾      
i = 1     

In [12]: diff(nges_uneval, n[5]).doit()
Out[12]: 1
```

Also notice that in the next SymPy version you will be able to derive symbols with symbolic indices:

```
In [13]: j = symbols("j")

In [13]: diff(n[i], n[j])
Out[13]: 
δ   
 j,i
```

Where you get the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

If you don't feel like installing the SymPy development version, just wait for the next full version (probably coming out this autumn), it will support derivatives of `IndexedBase`.

Comment: One quick question though. Do you know if it possible to define a indexed base function, i. e. f_i(T) with i being the index? So far I could not find anything in the documentation. Not a must have, but with this functionality I could write down my whole problem and tackle it with sympy in a sound way. Best regards.

Comment: I don't think that's currently supported. IndexedBase requires a symbol or a string as its argument. You may still try subclassing IndexedBase and override its methods, but that's a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the `IndexedBase` approach does not work (I would be interested to know also). You can, however, do the following:

```
import sympy as sp

numSpecies = 10
n = sp.symbols('n0:%d'%numSpecies)   # note that n equals the tuple (n0, n1, ..., n9)

ntot = sum(n)       # sum elements of n using the standard
                    # Python function for summing tuple elements
#ntot = sp.Add(*n)  # same result using Sympy function

sp.diff(ntot, n[5])
```

Comment: It has been fixed in the development version.

Comment: @FrancescoBonazzi Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear about what you want to do. However, perhaps this will help. Edited in response to two comments received.

```
from sympy import *

nspecies = 10
[var('n%s'%_) for _ in range(nspecies)]

expr = sympify('+'.join(['n%s'%_ for _ in range(nspecies)]))
expr
print ( diff(expr,n1) )

expr = sympify('n0**n1+n1**n2')
expr
print ( diff(expr,n1) )
```

Only the first expression responds to the original question. This is the output.

```
1
n0**n1*log(n0) + n1**n2*n2/n1
```

Comment: I didn't need to make a list of the vars!

Comment: Could you convert the image to code in text form? Currently it is hard to use/test your answer.

Comment: You can generate symbols directly without sympifying string.

Comment: @FrancescoBonazzi: Yes, however, you might want to create some arbitrarily complicated expression involving the variables, as suggested in the second expression above.

Comment: What about Add(*[...]) instead of sympify("+".join([...])) ?

Comment: Shortest form would be expr = Add(*symbols("n0:%" % nspecies))

Comment: @FrancescoBonazzi: Nice. I didn't know that. Still, I was merely trying to point out that sympify makes certain things possible. Not that I know all the features of sympi.